# Is having an "id" column in a table mandatory to work with BackPack?

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-8, laravel-backpack

I have a table with columns `color_id` and `list_id`. When I load a page with that specific model in Laravel BackPack, it throws an error:

```
SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "id" does not exist LINE 1: select * from "color_list" order by "id" desc l... ^ (SQL: select * from "color_list" order by "id" desc limit 10)
```

In general, this is correct. I do not have an `id` column since it's a pivot table. I assumed adding custom sorting would solve the problem so I added the following line in my controller's `setup()` method:

```
$this->crud->addClause('orderBy', 'color_id', 'DESC');
```

This didn't solve the problem and BackPack is still trying to search `id` column.

```
SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "id" does not exist LINE 1: ...color_list" order by "color_id" desc, "id" desc ... ^ (SQL: select * from "color_list" order by "color_id" desc, "id" desc limit 10)
```

Is there no way around it? Do I really need to add an `id` column to my table?

Comment: Can you show us your model? Sometimes people add relations, and they do not define any other columns than the default, and default is ID.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly my mistake. I had to manually write `protected $primaryKey = 'color_id`. So this is something that can't be controlled from BackPack but the model itself.

Comment: I would recommend to always have an id regardless. Good database structure to have an autoincremented column just named id in each table that is unique. It is especially good when you're paginating in laravel and got nothing else to order by, will prevent duplicates etc.

Comment: The *id* column is required because **your query references** it.  Postgres interprets a term in double quotes ("...") as a name reference. Your query is attempting to order by a column that does not exist, according to what you said your table contains.

Comment: Thank you @Stoff. I'll keep this in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding this to my model, I was able to solve it for the moment:

`protected $primaryKey = 'color_id';`

But is this really the only solution?

Comment: Indeed, models need a primary key, in order to be able to build an administration panel on top of them. Without a primary key... there's really no way to list/create/update/delete entries.

Comment: Sure there must be a Primary Key. But does it have to be a single `biginteger`? And does it have to be named `id`? The whole purpose of a link table (for example where you have a many-many relationship) is to relate two keys from other tables; a single field as key is not possible, calling either `id` would be wrong.